How to assign id's to records after using FLATTEN
In my data there is a field that has multiple emails that are comma separated. I am using FLATTEN to separate the emails into their own record keeping all other fields the same. I need to be able to create a new field that will assign an id to each email that was separated by the FLATTEN function.
The FLATTEN portion is working and I'm getting the emails split out but I don't know how to create the new id field. I'm working in Snowflake.
Example
Source Record:



ID
EMAIL_TO




1
email1,email2,email3


2
email4,email5



What I need:



ID
EMAIL_TO
NEW_DERIVED_ID




1
email1
1


1
email2
2


1
email3
3


2
email4
1


2
email5
2



CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYVIEW (
ID,
EMAIL_TO,
NEW_DERIVED_ID_FOR_EACH_SPLIT_EMAIL_TO_FIELD
) as (
        SELECT
        ID,
        collate(cast(replace(value, '"')as varchar),'en-ci-trim') as EMAIL_TO,
        NEW_DERIVED_ID_FOR_EACH_SPLIT_EMAIL_TO_FIELD
        FROM MYSOURCE as CM,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(CM.EMAIL_TO, ',')) as EMAIL_TO
        where EMAIL_TO is not null
);


Snowflake Flatten returns several fields as output:
SEQ, KEY,  PATH, INDEX,  VALUE & THIS
INDEX should provide you with what you need to generate an ID field without having to generate one manually with something like row_number() .  Assuming you want it sequenced from 1, you just need to add 1 to the INDEX:
create table emails as 
select ID,  EMAIL_TO
from (values (1, 'email1,email2,email3' )) as eml (ID, EMAIL_TO);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MYVIEW  as 
  SELECT
    ID,
    collate(cast(replace(value, '"')as varchar),'en-ci-trim') as EMAIL_TO,
    INDEX+1 NEW_DERIVED_ID_FOR_EACH_SPLIT_EMAIL_TO_FIELD
  FROM emails as CM,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(CM.EMAIL_TO, ',')) as EMAIL_TO
  where EMAIL_TO is not null
;
select * from myview;


Ok this is helpful, I should have researched the FLATTEN function a little more. The ID would need to restart at 1 for each original ID (I added in the example above). I think I could use some sort of where clause for that right?

EDIT: I tried it just how you had it and it worked! It just restarts the index for each burst record. Still doing testing to confirm but I think that did it. Thank you!

The output of the FLATTEN return rows consist of a fixed set of columns:
+-----+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| SEQ |  KEY | PATH | INDEX | VALUE | THIS |
|-----+------+------+-------+-------+------|

So your main query would be something like :
SELECT ID, 
       VALUE AS EMAIL, INDEX+1 AS NEW_DERIVED_ID
FROM MYSOURCE as CM,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(CM.EMAIL_TO, ',')) as f
WHERE EMAIL_TO is not null;

